# Filtering and sorting for account data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to optimize my code or see if there's a better way to do it. Given values for `acctData` and balances below, I need to return an array of accounts filtered by the user name.

```
const acctData = [
      {
        acctNum: "AAA - 1234",
        user: "Alice"
      },
      {
        acctNum: "AAA - 5231",
        user: "Bob"
      },
      {
        acctNum: "AAA - 9921",
        user: "Alice"
      },
      {
        acctNum: "AAA - 8191",
        user: "Alice"
      }
];

const balance = {
  "AAA - 1234": 4593.22,
  "AAA - 9921": 0,
  "AAA - 5231": 232142.5,
  "AAA - 8191": 4344
};

const combinedAccBalance = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(acctData));

const getAccountNumbers = (filterByUser) => {
  return combinedAccBalance
    .filter(acc => {
      acc.balance = balance[acc.acctNum];
      return acc.user === filterByUser;
    }).sort((a, b) => {
      return a.balance - b.balance;
    })
    .map(fa => {    
      return fa.acctNum;
    });
};

getAccountNumbers("Alice");
//Returns
["AAA - 9921", "AAA - 8191", "AAA - 1234"]
```